# Angular custom directive context

Tags: angular, directive

I have the following code block

```
<dx-data-grid ... >
<dxi-column dataField="Title" cellTemplate="cellTemplate"></dxi-column>
<div *dxTemplate="let cell of 'cellTemplate'">
    <div>{{cell.text}}</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to understand how is this built behind the scenes. Because the `*dxTemplate="let cell of 'cellTemplate'"`  is able to pick all the information from the `cellTemplate="cellTemplate"`. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not shure about the single comma arround cellTemplate

Comment: These directives with a * are called structural directives, which alter the DOM. Examples are NgIf and NgFor. You can learn more about them here https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives . This *dxTemplate probably does something similar to NgFor.

Comment: You are right, this is a structural directive, but i just can't figure out how the context is passed there. I can assure you the code is correct, it's a snippet for a grid component from the DevExtreme website.